# Using siunitx in captions?

Tags: captions, siunitx

I am using pdflatex(texlive 2011) to compile a document.
Unfortunately  it does not compile.

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\metre ->\ERROR 

l.69 ...feld  \num{6}{\metre} mal \num{6}{\metre}}
```

siunitx works for units in normal text, but using it in captions fails.
Is this a bug or misconfiguration. Under texlive 2009 it compiles flawlessly.

Here is my figure command

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \caption{\num{6}{\metre}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @elcojon: I've tided up the MWE so it is 'stand alone' and minimal.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Things will work correctly if you do not abuse `\num` :-)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\begin{figure}
  Some filler
  \caption{A caption \SI{6}{\metre}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Reason: the `\num` macro command takes one argument: a number. You therefore effectively have a free-standing unit after the `\num`, and these are not therefore correctly processed by `siunitx`.

---

To explain why this worked in TL2009, that had version 1 of `siunitx`. The older code created 'free-standing' units as standard, which was changed for version 2. 'Free-standing' units have various issues, including namespace issues: this change was quite deliberate. Of course, this means that something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{free-standing-units}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \caption{\num{6}{\metre}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

will work, but as it's not the correct use of `\num` I really don't encourage it!

Comment: You are right. And I appreciate your help a lot. Yet, I do have another problem very related to this. I might open another question.